# User/group permissions change when launching Docker container on remote server

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, rsync

I am trying to use a remote server to run experiments on Docker. The problem is that I have scripts that actively modify configuration files within the Docker container to run experiments, which I can only do if the user/group that owns the files does it (I do not have root access on the remote server).

On my local system, the user / group permissions are my personal user when accessed without launching the docker container. And as soon as the docker container is launched, the user / groups change to **alice / alice** by configuration as seen in the Dockerfile. But on the remote server, it shows as root / root even after launching in the docker container. Any suggestions?

Within my build/run shell script for Docker, I have the lines:

```
.
.
.
CURR_UID=$(id -u)
CURR_GID=$(id -g)

RUN_OPT="-u $CURR_UID:$CURR_GID --net=host --env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
--volume $XAUTHORITY:/home/alice/.Xauthority \
--volume /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
--privileged $MOUNT_DEVEL $MOUNT_LEARN \
--shm-size $SHM_SIZE $GPU_OPT $CONT_NAME \
-it $DETACH --rm $IMAGE_NAME:latest"

docker run $RUN_OPT
.
.
.
```

The run option -u $CURR_UID:$CURR_GID is supposed to set the user/group permissions to whatever user/group is running it at the moment. And within my **Dockerfile**:

```
.
.
.
# Working user
RUN groupadd --gid ${GROUP_ID} alice && \
    useradd -m -s /bin/bash -u ${USER_ID} -g ${GROUP_ID} alice && \
    echo "alice:alice" | chpasswd && adduser alice sudo
.
.
.
```

I can provide more information if needed, I really just need any help at all. Been at this for days. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: The `docker run -u` option will take precedence over whatever you set in the Dockerfile; the `RUN` line you show is unnecessary and has a couple of problems, and I'd remove it.  If you're running the script as root then the container will run as root too.

Answer (score 0):

In your docker container you can set the effective user with the directive:

`USER alice`

It is documented here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

Comment: Yes, sorry I do have this in my Dockerfile as it completes. And it works as expected on local system. The problem is with a remote server because the user/groups of files even after accessing them from within the container are set to root/root instead of alice/alice.

Comment: You may need to use the userid rather than the name.